# Program comes unresponsive after 30 minutes

Tags: vb.net, browser, refresh

I have an application I made that can log into social networks and constantly check to see when inactive accounts are reset. In this instance I am using Xbox's free gamertag change on their website used to see when these names are reset. I created an application where I log into Xbox.com and navigate to change gamertag page on the webbrowser where I type in what Gamertag I want in a textbox (An inactive tag that will reset soon) where I hit the "Autoclick" button, and it constantly tries to claim the account name. So I created this script, but then I realized it would time out too soon. The program would only last about 10 minutes on a fast speed (there are 3 speeds, slow - medium - fast), but it would last a bit longer on a slow speed. However, I realized I had to refresh the page every so seconds for it to work longer. Once I did this the application was a lot more endurable, and lasted about 30+ minutes. However, it STILL times out. There are people who make these scripts that last for days, but I am just aiming for one day. So I am asking if anyone knows how I can improve this? Here is parts of my script. I have a button that once clicked enables the timer to autoclick the claim button.

So my button:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 40
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        Timer1.Interval = 175
    Else
        Timer1.Interval = 500
    End If

    If ((WebBrowser1.IsBusy)) Then



    Else

        Timer1.Enabled = True



    End If


End Sub
```

and then Timer1, which does the autoclicking, but also has the refresh property to make it more endurable:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick



    If Not number_of_ticks > 170 Then
        number_of_ticks += 1
        If ((WebBrowser1.IsBusy)) Then
        Else
            If WebBrowser1.Url.ToString = "https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag" Then


                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("NewGamertag").SetAttribute("value", txtTurbo.Text)

                WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("claimIt").InvokeMember("Click")
            Else

                WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://live.xbox.com/en-US/ChangeGamertag")


            End If
        End If

    Else
        'number_of_ticks has exceed the maximum amount of allowed ticks
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        WebBrowser1.Refresh()

        number_of_ticks = 0
        Timer1.Enabled = True



    End If



End Sub
```

I am not sure of many ways to make it last longer, but if anyone has any clues on how this can be done i'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you're saying that the more often you refresh the page, the less time until you get logged out. The Timer's interval property is measured in milliseconds, at the moment your slowest setting is 170 ticks at 500 milliseconds each. So you're checking every 85 seconds whether that nick is now available. You could compromise quite a lot on that i think, instead setting the interval to 1000 or 2000.

Your other option would be to navigate to the login page every 30 minutes and log in again?

ps.

Instead of using:

```
If ((WebBrowser1.IsBusy)) Then
    Else
        'code
```

You could just use:

```
If not WebBrowser1.IsBusy Then
    'code
```

It looks slightly easier to read imo.

sidebar: i think your program is quite cool :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with WebBrowser object in several years, but I believe its possible you could be getting stuck on endless `WebBrowser1.IsBusy`. Its similar to when you browse to a page and sometimes it never ends loading. In that case, you would need to have some kind of timeout mechanixm to stop with `WebBrowser1.Stop` and then try to navigate to the page again.

Or simply ignore the isbusy and force the stop before refreshing the page. increase the timer because your longest timer of 500 is in fact 500 milliseconds, which is 0.5 seconds - your webpage may not load that fast.